# in phonegap . is it nessecary to include cardova-2.0.0.js in all html page?

Tags: javascript, cordova

in phonegap . is it nessecary to include cardova-2.0.0.js in all  html page  ?

```
in other html page it not display device property in ondeviceready() function and if i include second time in another page cardova is not loading......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nop, its not necessary to do this for all the pages.

Its not recommended to use different pages in the app. still if you need to do this Use HTML5 element   for paging in the app. Its not a proper code just google it. and you find the solution.

Comment: your mean i should use only one html page in phonegap

Comment: but i see many page html page in phonegap project like employee list

Comment: Yes you can add multiple pages and for each page you have to include phonegap.js or cordova.js to each page. but its not a recommended way to do that. Use HTML5

Comment: <body onload="init()">
    <div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Header text</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="page-content">
            <div data-role="content">
                <h1>Content here...</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <h1>More content here...</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Footer text</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

Use the above code to give feel like pages and with minimal Javascript

Comment: Why is it not recommended? And in an application that consists largely of HTML, CSS and JavaScript, how exactly would this be achieved? Perhaps you could modify your existing answer to include some more information to qualify your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If your navigation is done by something like Jquery Mobile where the secondary pages are loaded via Ajax, your Javascript code will remain from your index.html page.

However, if your code is navigating the user directly to your new page, it would need the new Javascript loaded because it wouldn't already exist.